# Getting occasional 403s from https://eventgw.twilio.com/v2/EndpointMetrics

Tags: twilio, twilio-click-to-call

When establishing a call using Twilio, many many POSTs are made to https://eventgw.twilio.com/v2/EndpointMetrics, and I've noticed in our javascript error tracking service that some of our users get 403s from these calls.  In the last week, there have been 19 users getting 2,600 errors.  Can anyone from Twilio tell me what the calls are, whether these errors are benign and I should ignore them, and whether there is any way to disable these?  For a single short call I'm seeing 34 separate POST requests to this endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check that when you get these errors, your clients [Access](https://www.twilio.com/docs/iam/access-tokens) or [Capability](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/capability-tokens) token didn't expire?